# Using static C library in swift, cannot find module

Tags: swift, static-libraries, static-linking

I need to create a swift wrapper for a C library for use on both iOS and macOS. 
I have added the `.a` to the frameworks list and include it in `library search path`. I have added the header file to project and added it to `User header search paths` and I have added a `module.modulemap` to the project as well. Looking like this:

```
module codinglibc [system][extern_c] {
    header “codinglibc.h”
    export *
}
```

But when I import the module in Swift:

```
import Foundation

import codinglibc
```

I get this error message: `No such module 'codinglibc'`.

The project is a Cocoa Framework and I have been following this guide: https://medium.com/swift-and-ios-writing/using-a-c-library-inside-a-swift-framework-d041d7b701d9

I have looked at a lot of stackoverflow answers but most have been solved by adding import paths, which I already have done and Xcode can find both the header file and the static library so that is not the issue.

So: 
1. Have I done something obviously wrong which I have missed?
2. Should I use briding headers instead?

**Edit:** I tried enabling `Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules` 
 still no success

Comment: Is the C library multi-architectural? Does it work on iPhones, iPads, simulators, etc?

Comment: @hgale yes it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty trivial, yet annoying.

If you add the `module.modulemap` in an Xcode project, Xcode will not register it as "to be imported", so what you need to do is to add the path to you `module.modulemap` file in the header includes.

Comment: I’m trying to do exactly what you were doing here. Can you post in your answer what you did exactly? It’s unclear to me.

Comment: @hgale sorry for late reply, where you set the build settings you can add header includes parts. That is where I added the path to the module.modulemap :)